# For which values of $n$ is $f$ one-to-one/onto?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> for each $n \in \mathbb Z$ the mapping $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ is defined by $f(x) = nx$.

Let $z_1, z_2, n \in \mathbb Z.$ Let $nz_1 = nz_2$. Then $z_1 =z_2.$ Now suppose $n = 0,$ and $0z_1 = 0z_2.$ I am not sure, but it looks like this equation has no solution. So, $f$ is one-to-one for all $n \in \mathbb Z - \{0\}.$ If what I wrote is correct, how do I exclude all values of $n$ that make $f$ non-one-to-one?

To prove $f$ is onto, we need to find an $x$ such that $nx = y.$ So, let $x = yn^{-1}.$ Then $f(x) = nn^{-1}y.$ Letting $n = 1$ and $n = -1$ don't change anything, so these two values of $n$ make $f$ surjective. But how do we show these are the only valid $n$ granted what I wrote above makes sense?

Please, see if what I wrote is true/false.

edit: $0z_1 = 0z_2 \to 0 = 0$ which is true for infinite number of solutions. I guess that part was incorrect.

Comment: When you take the inverse, you're doing a multiplicative inverse, right? And the multiplicative inverses of integers (except 1 and -1) don't exist inside the integers (try solving $xy =1$), so you can say that those two are the only possible values.

Comment: To exclude 0 in the first part, I don't know if this is what you mean but we usually write $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\neq 0}$

Comment: @ shardulc, does everything else make sense, though?

Comment: Yes, I think it does.

Comment: I made edited my OP. What do you think of that?

Comment: Yes, it has an infinite number of solutions but an infinite number of them have $z_1=z_2$, and an infinite number of them do not. So we can't say the function is one-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ define $f_n:\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}:x\mapsto nx$.

**Claim 1:** The map $f_n$ is injective if and only if $n\neq 0$.

*Proof:* If $n=0$, we have $f_0(x)=0=f_0(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$; thus $f_0$ is not injective.  If $n\neq0$ we have $nx=f_n(x)=f_n(y)=ny$ implies $x=y$ as $\Bbb{Z}$ is an integral domain; thus $f_n$ is injective for all $n\neq0$.

**Claim 2:** The map $f_n$ is surjective if and only if $n\in\{-1,1\}$.

*Proof:* Immediately $f_1=id_{\Bbb{Z}}$ is surjective.  Now for all $x\in\Bbb Z$ we have $f_{-1}(-x)=x$ and so $f_{-1}$ is surjective.  Thus $n\in\{-1,1\}$ implies $f_n$ is surjective.  Now $1$ is divisible only by $1$ and $-1$.  Thus $1=f_n(x)=nx$ implies either $n=1=x$ or $n=-1=x$.  Thus $1\notin{\rm im}(f_n)$ whenever $n\notin\{-1,1\}$, and $f_n$ is not surjective.

**Corollary:** The map $f_n$ is a bijection if and only if $n\in\{-1,1\}$.

*Proof:* Immediate from Claim 1 and Claim 2.